# Why HttpListenerException is raised

Tags: wcf

From time to time, we got this HttpListenerException:
Does anyone know in what case the exception could be raised ?

Call Stak as follows:
  Exception Messages:

```
 HttpListenerException: An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection
Type         : System.Net.HttpListenerException, System, Version=4.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message      : An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection
Source       : System
ErrorCode    : 1229
NativeErrorCode: 1229
TargetSite   : Boolean ReadAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs)
Stack Trace  :    at  System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.ReadAsyncFast(HttpListenerAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.<ReadAsyncCore>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at         System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.WebSocketOperation.<Process>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketBase.<ReceiveAsyncCore>d__45.MoveNext()
TargetSite   : 
Stack Trace  : The stack trace is unavailable.
```

Comment: I'm _assuming_ that you get this issue while trying to make a service call from your wcf application. Give some context on the issue or the code whether this issue occurs rather than just exception message alone.

Comment: thanks, 

the problem is, we don't know where it was raised, after added try...catch to every suspicious place.

the current finding is that it happened when we call 'Abort' to close the channel,  and later we use 'Close' instead of 'Abort',the exceptions get less, but still, we cannot eliminate that exception.